# Convert Tabular CLI output to JSON format in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, tabular

I need to convert he below output to Json format in python.

How can i do it ?

```
switch# sh mod
Mod  Ports  Module-Type                         Model              Status
---  -----  ----------------------------------- ------------------ ----------
1    48     1/2/4/8 Gbps FC/Supervisor-3        DS-C9148-K9-SUP    active *

Mod  Sw              Hw      World-Wide-Name(s) (WWN)
---  --------------  ------  --------------------------------------------------
1    6.2(17)         1.1     20:01:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8 to 20:30:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8


Mod  MAC-Address(es)                         Serial-Num
---  --------------------------------------  ----------
1    c0-8c-60-65-82-dc to c0-8c-60-65-82-df  JAF1736ALLM
```

Input 1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGsY4.jpg

Input 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDGcB.jpg

Comment: 1. what should the output looks like, and 2. what have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: I'd say you have to use complex regular ex or a stateful line parser. Unluckily both will be somewhere between challenging and ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the '---' separators to define the slices of each key and value line to build up each key value. (From your example, I'm guessing there are multiple "Mod"s, with unique Mod values, so I used this field for the overall accumulator key.)

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re
from itertools import groupby

sample = """\
Mod  Ports  Module-Type                         Model              Status
---  -----  ----------------------------------- ------------------ ----------
1    48     1/2/4/8 Gbps FC/Supervisor-3        DS-C9148-K9-SUP    active *
2    48     1/2/4/8 Gbps FC/Supervisor-3        DS-C9148-K9-SUP    active *

Mod  Sw              Hw      World-Wide-Name(s) (WWN)
---  --------------  ------  --------------------------------------------------
1    6.2(17)         1.1     20:01:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8 to 20:30:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8
2    6.2(17)         1.1     20:01:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8 to 20:30:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8

Mod  MAC-Address(es)                         Serial-Num
---  --------------------------------------  ----------
1    c0-8c-60-65-82-dc to c0-8c-60-65-82-df  JAF1736ALLM
2    c0-8c-60-65-82-ec to c0-8c-60-65-82-ef  JAF1736AXXX

Xbar Ports Module-Type Model Status
---- ----- ----------- ----- ------
1    0     Fabric 1    ABC   ok

Xbar Sw Hw
---- -- ---
1    NA 1.0

"""

all_input_lines = sample.splitlines()
mod_accum = defaultdict(dict)
xbar_accum = defaultdict(dict)

for is_blank, input_lines_iter in groupby(all_input_lines, 
                                          key=lambda s: not bool(s.strip())):
    input_lines = list(input_lines_iter)
    if is_blank:
        continue

    # assume first two lines are field names and separator dashes
    names, dashes = input_lines[:2]

    # make sure dashes line is all '---' separators
    if not all(ss == set('-') for ss in map(set, dashes.split())):
        print("invalid line group found, skipping...")
        print('-'*40)
        print('\n'.join(input_lines))
        print('-'*40)
        continue

    # use regex to get start/end of each '---' divider, and make slices
    spans = (match.span() for match in re.finditer('-+', dashes))
    slices = [slice(sp[0], sp[1]+1) for sp in spans]

    names = [names[sl].rstrip() for sl in slices]

    # is this a module or an xbar?
    if 'Mod' in names:
        key = 'Mod'
        accum = mod_accum
    elif 'Xbar' in names:
        key = 'Xbar'
        accum = xbar_accum
    else:
        raise ValueError("no Mod or Xbar name in row names ({})".format(
                            ",".join(names)))

    for line in input_lines:
        # use slices to extract data from values, make into a dict
        row_dict = dict(zip(names, (line[sl].rstrip() for sl in slices)))

        # accumulate these values into any previous ones collected for this Mod
        accum[row_dict[key]].update(row_dict)

# print out what we got
import json
all_data = {"Modules": mod_accum, "Xbars": xbar_accum}
print(json.dumps(all_data, indent=2))
```

Prints:

```
{
  "Modules": {
    "2": {
      "World-Wide-Name(s) (WWN)": "20:01:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8 to 20:30:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8",
      "Module-Type": "1/2/4/8 Gbps FC/Supervisor-3",
      "Ports": "48",
      "Sw": "6.2(17)",
      "Hw": "1.1",
      "Model": "DS-C9148-K9-SUP",
      "Status": "active *",
      "Serial-Num": "JAF1736AXXX",
      "MAC-Address(es)": "c0-8c-60-65-82-ec to c0-8c-60-65-82-ef",
      "Mod": "2"
    },
    "1": {
      "World-Wide-Name(s) (WWN)": "20:01:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8 to 20:30:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8",
      "Module-Type": "1/2/4/8 Gbps FC/Supervisor-3",
      "Ports": "48",
      "Sw": "6.2(17)",
      "Hw": "1.1",
      "Model": "DS-C9148-K9-SUP",
      "Status": "active *",
      "Serial-Num": "JAF1736ALLM",
      "MAC-Address(es)": "c0-8c-60-65-82-dc to c0-8c-60-65-82-df",
      "Mod": "1"
    }
  },
  "Xbars": {
    "1": {
      "Module-Type": "Fabric 1",
      "Ports": "0",
      "Sw": "NA",
      "Hw": "1.0",
      "Model": "ABC",
      "Status": "ok",
      "Xbar": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paul. The above code works perfectly fine for one module.
 However for input 1. its throwing key error as there is a new rowname 'xbar' in this. Any idea how we can handle this.

 Also it is not iterating for next set of modules for input 2.

Comment: After writing this, I had a feeling that this would be the case for multiple modules. Rewritten to use itertools.groupby to pull out groups of lines, with a little error-checking in case we get a group of non-data lines. You didn't learn much Python from this, but perhaps this will be a useful code example for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but it isn't pretty. Assume your entire output is in `text`.

```
import re
lines = text.split("\n")
keylines = [line for i, line in enumerate(lines) if len(lines)>(i+1) and "---" in lines[i+1]]
vallines = [line for i, line in enumerate(lines) if i!=0 and "---" in lines[i-1]]
keys = re.split("  +", "  ".join(keylines))
vals = re.split("  +", "  ".join(vallines))
result = dict(zip(keys, vals))
```

Output:

```
{
  "Mod": "1",
  "Ports": "48",
  "Module-Type": "1/2/4/8 Gbps FC/Supervisor-3",
  "Model": "DS-C9148-K9-SUP",
  "Status": "active *",
  "Sw": "6.2(17)",
  "Hw": "1.1",
  "World-Wide-Name(s) (WWN)": "20:01:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8 to 20:30:54:7f:ee:df:88:f8",
  "MAC-Address(es)": "c0-8c-60-65-82-dc to c0-8c-60-65-82-df",
  "Serial-Num": "JAF1736ALLM"
}
```

It makes the following assumptions, and will break when they are not true:

- No values contain more than one space in succession.
- There are at least two spaces between "fields".
- In the line with the dashes, there is at least one segment that is 3 dashes long.